# Print to bluetooth printer after connecting, what command to print?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth

I've been trying to print to a thermal bluetooth printer using web bluetooth for eternity. I connect to the printer but don't know what command to use to send characters to the printer. No examples available online. It seems that everyone is doing it using android app but if I can connect to the printer, then I can send a file to print using the device, right?

Here is my code to connect :

```
function getdevices(){
    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ name: ['BlueTooth Printer'] }] })
.then(device => { 
    console.log(device)
    // Attempts to connect to remote GATT Server.
  return device.gatt.connect();
})
.then(server => { 
    console.log("server log :", server) 
}) 
.catch(error => { console.error(error); });
```

console.log for device is showing my printer :

```
gatt
: 
BluetoothRemoteGATTServer {device: BluetoothDevice, connected: true}
id
: 
"t+kEYShfsUR6puq1km6P+cc=="
name
: 
"BlueTooth Printer"
onadvertisementreceived
: 
null
ongattserverdisconnected
: 
null
watchingAdvertisements
: 
false
```

and the server log is showing the following :

```
server log : 
BluetoothRemoteGATTServer {device: BluetoothDevice, connected: true}
connected
: 
true
device
: 
BluetoothDevice {id: 't+kEYShfsUR6puq1km6P4Q==', name: 'BlueTooth Printer', gatt: BluetoothRemoteGATTServer, ongattserverdisconnected: null, watchingAdvertisements: false, …}
[[Prototype]]
: 
BluetoothRemoteGATTServer
```

Now the question is : it says connected, so how to communicate with the printer?
do I start server.open?
server.print?
server.print(file)?

What should you do to print once you're connected to the bluetooth printer?

Comment: As this is a very hardware dependent question, and without knowing your hardware, have you tried the [Basic Printing Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/basic-printing-profile-1-2/)?

Comment: In Android, you just create socket connection/rfchannel and print from any bluetooth printer. Regardless of their hardware. So I would assume there is a socket connection or something from the webBluetooth that I could use. That was my hope. Clearly there is not many answers so I'll go back to use Android to print from bluetooth printers. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.